# Is there a way to black-out a website when someone tries to stream it or take a screenshot of it? Kinda like DRM protection?

Tags: html, css, security, drm

I know nothing about this type of stuff, I don't have a legal copyright or anything, I just want to make it so if anyone tried streaming the site, the entire site (viewport) would just go black. Just like how Netflix DRM protects their videos. (I do understand that's very different though)

Does anyone know a simple solution? Nothing too crazy, is this even possible? Again, I don't know anything about this type of stuff so I'm sorry if this a dumb question.

I'm sorry for the confusion, this is a very specific question but lets say someone tried to take screenshots or if they were streaming their screen, the entire site would just be blacked out, its for a very odd intention but any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Closest thing is at the native app level - android gives you the ability to block screenshotting in apps, which is utilized by as you mentioned Netflix.

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible. Consider that someone could point a camera at the screen and stream that, which you have no hope of detecting. As for how Netflix "protects" their videos, ask yourself how any of their content ended up on pirate sites.